# Spring REST Huge response causes response writer to be called more than once

Tags: java, spring

I have a really simple controller action that accesses a service layer and eventually comes back with a huge response. The response gets partially sent, but it, in random places, ends up looking like this:

`...,"dimensions":{"width":400,"height":394},"hostedAtS3":true},"`

and I get the following exception:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response`

The controller for this one is dead simple:

```
@JsonView(value = StickerPackView.Admin.class)
@ApiOperation(value = "[ADMIN] Lists all categories regardless visibility", response = StickerCategory.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "/categories/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity getCategories(Principal principal) {
    return new ResponseEntity(stickerService.getAllCategories(), OK);
}
```

First thing I tried was to make it `DeferredResult` or `Callable` thinking that maybe it needed a longer time to generate the response. Unfortunately, it wasn't. When I left the method there and ended up with returning some smaller response - like single category - it was OK.

I have no clue how to deal with it. Here is [full stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/BwqeAjT8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did some debugging and found out that it isn't related to anything remotely related to JSON, length or anything like that. It was corrupted data. One of getters in particular model generated its response based on data which was nullified. Recent change in domain model allowed it to be null and this method wasn't adjusted for that. To find it i modified my controller action from my question to:

```
@JsonView(value = StickerPackView.Admin.class)
@ApiOperation(value = "[ADMIN] Lists all categories regardless visibility", response = StickerCategory.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "/categories/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity getCategories(Principal principal, ObjectMapper mapper) throws JsonProcessingException {
    final Collection<StickerCategory> categories = stickerService.getAllCategories();
    final String s = mapper.writeValueAsString(categories);
    return new ResponseEntity(s.length(), OK);
}
```

In this way serialization error wasn't hidden behind Spring Json serialization magic and exposed everything to me. I've lost too much time on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this is not a problem with a general understanding of HTTP.

> Basic rule of HTTP: one request, one response. You can only send back
>   one thing to a request.

You mentioned that when you are sending only one category it works. Maybe, if you are processing huge amount of data, your controller process it as a multiple responses. The code that you provided is limited, it is hard to say what exactly causes an error.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well. There is not a lot more to show regarding controller. The case here is amount of data that needs to be transferred to the client. I've seen services that return even more data in single request, but in fact - separating this huge response into smaller ones + HATEOAS to help people who are implementing this api with walking around resources is a acceptable workaround.